# power set of $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So last night when working on my discrete math homework I needed to find the power set of
$\{1,2,3,4\}$
I fully understand how to find power sets, and I understand that the cardinality of the resulting set can be found by $2^n$, where $n=$ cardinality of the original set, and I wrote out my answer, but then when I counted the number of elements in the new set I only counted $15$. I looked for so long last night, trying to figure out which subset I was missing but I couldn't figure it out. This is the answer that I have:
$$\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\},\varnothing\}$$
Can somebody figure out what I'm missing because this is frustrating the hell out of me. I thought that after I slept on it I would be able to figure out which subset is missing, but this morning, no matter how much I look at it, I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

The one you are missing is $\{1,3,4\}$  A good way to find it is to count the number of subsets with each number of elements.  You have four singletons and six pairs, which are the right number, but only three triplets.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I'm hitting myself now seeing that I had missed that one.

Comment: To carry this answer further:  There should be ${4\choose 0}=1$ empty set, ${4\choose 1} =4$ singletons, ${4\choose 2}=6$ pairs, ${4 \choose 3}=4$ triplets, and ${4\choose 4}$ entire sets.

Comment: You can also count in binary from 0000 up to 1111, and verify you've listed each corresponding subset. But this is less elegant than the other suggestions, and should be reserved as a final resort.

Answer (score 2):

Good way of thinking $n-1-$element subsets of the $n-$element set $\{1, 2, …, n\}$ is as follows: the subset without the element $1$, the subset without the element $2$, and so on. You have “without $1$”, “without $3$”, “without $4$” but miss the “without $2$” one.